# Network connection icon has disappeared from the panel in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, indicator, 13.10, panel

I successfully installed Ubuntu 13.10 from Ubuntu 13.04. When I tried to install Java in the terminal, I got a message that said: some repository files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

When I rebooted the computer, the network connection icon had disappeared from the panel. How can I restore the network connection icon to my panel?

Comment: Please write your question in English.

Answer (score 1):

**Try it once**

- Open terminal and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall indicator-network
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```
- Logout/restart your system.

Comment: The second command wants to install 47 packages. Why so many?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen: I'm not sure why it shows that much packages. But be sure that it will only install the packages, non of the packages are going to be removed.. If you could post the output it would be better.. :)